# Is pitched memory allocation more efficient with two-dimensional arrays?

Tags: c, optimization, cuda

I am implementing an application using CUDA with a compute capability `1.3` GPU that involves scanning a two-dimensional array for the locations where a smaller two-dimensional array occurs. Up until now, both arrays were allocated using `cudaMallocPitch()` and transferred using `cudaMemcpy2D()` to meet the memory alignment requirements for coalescing.

During the first optimization steps, I am trying to coalescence the memory accesses to global memory by collectively reading data to the shared memory. As a test in the unoptimized code (where, for example, there is divergent branching and the memory accesses to the global memory are not coalesced ) I allocated the bigger array using `cudaMalloc()` and found that the performance improved by a factor of up to `50%`. How is this possible?

Comment: No, nothing like that. By unoptimized, as stated in the text, i refer to GPU specific optimizations; for example memory access patterns and thread divergence

Comment: Missed the word "the" before "unoptimized", my bad.

Answer (score 3):

cudaMallocPitch() ensure that the starting address of each row in the 2-D array (row-major) is a multiple of 2^N (N is 7~10 depending on the compute capability).

Whether the accesss is more efficient depends on not only the data alignment but also your compute capability, global mem access manner and sometimes the cache configuration.

This blog explains the great bandwidth reduction of mis-aligned data access on early compute capability, which could be an A to your Q.

https://developer.nvidia.com/content/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-cc-kernels

Since the performance depends on many factors, you may have to post your device module type and the kernel code as well to allow further investigation.

Comment: The article mentions the following:

"For (...) devices with compute capability of 1.2 or 1.3, misaligned accesses are less problematic. Basically, the misaligned accesses of contiguous data by a half warp of threads are serviced in a few transactions that “cover” the requested data. There is still a performance penalty relative to the aligned case due both to unrequested data being transferred and to some overlap of data requested by different half-warps (...)"

This refers to 1D arrays and it is according to the expected results, but in my results i have a completely different picture

Comment: @charis What is the size of your 2 arrays? If the cudaMalloc() approach is quicker. The reason could be the higher cache miss rate of the cudaMallocPitch() approach. Since the rows of the array are seperated by the padding space allocated by cudaMallocPitch()

Comment: Are you sure about the starting address of each row being a multiple of 2^7-2^10? I believe that a memory transaction of 32, 64 or 128 bytes is aligned when the first address of every 32, 64 or 128 bytes memory segment respectively is a multiple of its size, at least for compute capability 1.3 devices

Answer (score 3):

As already indicated by kangshiyin, the improvements arising from the use of `cudaMallocPitch` depend on the compute capability and are expected to be more significant for older ones. However, for most recent compute capabilities, pitched memory allocation does not seem to lead to a relevant speedup.

The code below provides a performance testbench between the uses of non-pitched and pitched memories. In particular, the code performs the summation between three (non-pitched or pitched) matrices. The reason for dealing with three matrices is the need to highlight memory transactions as compared to computation, so to highlight the differences between non-pitched and pitched allocations. Below are the timing results for a `GTX 960` card and a `GT 920M` cards.

**GTX 960**

```
Non-pitched - Time = 3.242208; Memory = 65320000 bytes
Pitched     - Time = 3.150944; Memory = 65433600 bytes
```

**GT 920M**

```
Non-pitched - Time = 20.496799; Memory = 65320000 bytes
Pitched     - Time = 20.418560; Memory = 65433600 bytes
```

As it can be seen, there is not much difference in the two implementations for the two cards. The above results also show the increase in memory occupancy due to the use of pitched memory allocation.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<device_launch_parameters.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE_x 16
#define BLOCKSIZE_y 16

/******************/
/* TEST KERNEL 2D */
/******************/
__global__ void test_kernel_2D(float * __restrict__ devPtrA, float * __restrict__ devPtrB, float * __restrict__ devPtrC, const int Nrows, const int Ncols)
{
    int    tidx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int    tidy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((tidx < Ncols) && (tidy < Nrows)) {
        devPtrA[tidy * Ncols + tidx] = devPtrA[tidy * Ncols + tidx] + devPtrB[tidy * Ncols + tidx] + devPtrC[tidy * Ncols + tidx];
    }
}

/**************************/
/* TEST KERNEL PITCHED 2D */
/**************************/
__global__ void test_kernel_Pitched_2D(float * __restrict__ devPtrA, float * __restrict__ devPtrB, float * __restrict__ devPtrC, const size_t pitchA, const size_t pitchB, const size_t pitchC, const int Nrows, const int Ncols)
{
    int    tidx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int    tidy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((tidx < Ncols) && (tidy < Nrows))
    {
        float *row_a = (float *)((char*)devPtrA + tidy * pitchA);
        float *row_b = (float *)((char*)devPtrB + tidy * pitchB);
        float *row_c = (float *)((char*)devPtrC + tidy * pitchC);
        row_a[tidx] = row_a[tidx] + row_b[tidx] + row_c[tidx];
    }
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int Nrows = 7100;
    const int Ncols = 2300;

    TimingGPU timerGPU;

    float *hostPtrA = (float *)malloc(Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float));
    float *hostPtrB = (float *)malloc(Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float));
    float *hostPtrC = (float *)malloc(Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float));
    float *devPtrA, *devPtrPitchedA;
    float *devPtrB, *devPtrPitchedB;
    float *devPtrC, *devPtrPitchedC;
    size_t pitchA, pitchB, pitchC;

    for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++) {
        hostPtrA[i * Ncols + j] = 1.f;
        hostPtrB[i * Ncols + j] = 2.f;
        hostPtrC[i * Ncols + j] = 3.f;
        //printf("row %i column %i value %f \n", i, j, hostPtr[i][j]);
        }

    // --- 2D non-pitched allocation and host->device memcopy
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&devPtrA, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&devPtrB, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&devPtrC, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(devPtrA, hostPtrA, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(devPtrB, hostPtrB, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(devPtrC, hostPtrC, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- 2D pitched allocation and host->device memcopy
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch(&devPtrPitchedA, &pitchA, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch(&devPtrPitchedB, &pitchB, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch(&devPtrPitchedC, &pitchC, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(devPtrPitchedA, pitchA, hostPtrA, Ncols * sizeof(float), Ncols*sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(devPtrPitchedB, pitchB, hostPtrB, Ncols * sizeof(float), Ncols*sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(devPtrPitchedC, pitchC, hostPtrC, Ncols * sizeof(float), Ncols*sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    dim3 gridSize(iDivUp(Ncols, BLOCKSIZE_x), iDivUp(Nrows, BLOCKSIZE_y));
    dim3 blockSize(BLOCKSIZE_y, BLOCKSIZE_x);

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    test_kernel_2D << <gridSize, blockSize >> >(devPtrA, devPtrB, devPtrC, Nrows, Ncols);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    printf("Non-pitched - Time = %f; Memory = %i bytes \n", timerGPU.GetCounter(), Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float));

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    test_kernel_Pitched_2D << <gridSize, blockSize >> >(devPtrPitchedA, devPtrPitchedB, devPtrPitchedC, pitchA, pitchB, pitchC, Nrows, Ncols);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    printf("Pitched - Time = %f; Memory = %i bytes \n", timerGPU.GetCounter(), Nrows * pitchA);

    //gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(hostPtr, Ncols * sizeof(float), devPtrPitched, pitch, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(hostPtrA, devPtrA, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(hostPtrB, devPtrB, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(hostPtrC, devPtrC, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    //for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) 
    //  for (int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++) 
    //      printf("row %i column %i value %f \n", i, j, hostPtr[i * Ncols + j]);

    return 0;

}
```